# play asx or pls format with php

Tags: php, audio, stream, streaming, asx

Is it possible to play either format through PHP? I don't want to use jw player or Flash. I just want it to auto play when loaded through PHP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is typically used on a server, to render HTML to clients. It *can* be used for systems programming tasks, but isn't very well suited to the task.

Playing video or audio requires *client* software. The choice of language for the server is irrelevant, as the client player could be built-in "Media Player" or "preview" applications, or `mplayer` or `vlc`, or the software could be something that is embedded (or embeddable) in web browsers. HTML5 will make playing video without goofy browser plugins *easier*, but as there is no standard on video *format*, that won't be an awesome solution for a long time, and in the meantime, you get to use something goofy like jwplayer or flash to render video to clients.

But which program you use has nothing to do with the programming language used on the server-side to distribute or promote those files to users.